# Sort ListView from SQLite using ORDER BY

Tags: android

I have a ListView populated by a series of data from an SQLite Database. Now I want to sort the list based on "project_title" column. As far as I know we need to use ORDER BY.

So I put that on the query like this:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstText);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setAdapter(new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitems,
                managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(Provider.CONTENT_URI,
                        Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                        Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE,
                        Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE, Database.Project.C_PROJECTDESCRIPTION, Database.Project.C_BIGIMAGE}, "SELECT " + "project_title" 
                       +" FROM "+"Project"+" ORDER BY "+"project_title"+" COLLATE NOCASE ASC", null, null),
                new String[] { Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE,
                        Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE, Database.Project.C_PROJECTDESCRIPTION}, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt_title, R.id.image, R.id.txt_list_desc}));
```

But then nothing was displayed on the ListView. How should I correct my ORDER BY query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Something Like This...

```
String[] all_columns = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                            Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE,
                            Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE,
                            Database.Project.C_PROJECTDESCRIPTION,
                            Database.Project.C_BIGIMAGE};



 Cursor c = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, all_columns , whereClause, null, null, null, "project_title asc",null);
```